# UItableView with searchDisplayController changed the contentoffset when scrolling in ios7

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have `UITableView` with `searchDisplayController` as table `headerView`(not a section header). When first time  the `contenoffset` is :{0, 0} this is correct. But when scroll to up and down then last `contentOffset` value on my console is :{0,44}. Why it is happen? Please help me..

Comment: contentOffset changed because i can't see my search bar (its behind navigation bar).

Answer (score 0):

In ios7,don’t set directly add 'tableHeaderView' as 'UISearchBar'.Firstly i added my 'UISearchBar' to plain 'UIView',then set my 'tableHeaderView' as plain 'UIView'.I solve my issue...